# how to import within windows fcntl module

Tags: python

I wanna find an our module in windows case.
the module name is "fcntl" within python.
how can i import same as our module?
Please help me... IF the module don't have open souce, 
Please send me or give me our website URL.

```
import sys
import socket
import argparse
import os
import signal
import struct
import fcntl


from xmlrpc.server import fcntl
SIOCSIFADDR = 0x8916

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

def get_mac_addr(ifname):
  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
  info = fcntl.ioctl(s.fileno(), 0x8927,  struct.pack('256s', bytes(ifname[:15], 'utf-8')))
  return ''.join(['%02x:' % b for b in info[18:24]])[:-1]

get_mac_addr('192.168.0.1')
```

Comment: No, ask the actual question you have: "How do I get the MAC address for a given adapter in Windows?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The substitute of fcntl on windows are win32api calls. The usage is completely different.

Comment: ahh.. I wanna change my ip address. for example, same as vpn situation.

Comment: Thank you so much!